# Java: problem loading stylesheet

Tags: java, xml

**Problem:**

I'm trying to load a stylesheet in Java but I get an error stateing it isn't a stylesheet.

**The Error:**

ERROR:  'The input document is not a stylesheet (the XSL namespace is not declared in the root element).'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:825)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:614)

**My Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         String XSLT2 =
            "<xsl:stylesheet \n" +
            "  xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" \n" +
            "  version=\"1.0\"\n" +
            "  >\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</xsl:stylesheet>";

        String XML = "<foo></foo>";

        StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(XSLT2));
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsltSource);
    }
```

Comment: Running that locally under Java 1.6 results in no errors.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I guess it has something to do with now my IDE is setup.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that having the Piccolo xml parser in my classpath is causing the problem:  http://piccolo.sourceforge.net/.

Not sure exactly what is going on here.

-Dave

Comment: It bundles an old version of some xml libraries.  If I take those out of the jar, all is well.